# How to display coloured text if colouring code in filecontent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm absolutely new in Python proramming and I would like to ask something:

I've a text file and read that content with python:

```
with open("help/myhelp.help", "r") as f:
   for line in f:
      print(line, end='')
```

Content of file:

```
Usage: \033[00;33mcommand [options] do-sth '<param1>;<param2>   **'  \033[0m
```

...but colour did not change. If I copy the text line and put it into python *print()* function it works fine.

So after I've read content of the file I want to display coloured rows...

Is it possible somehow to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the color sequences don't get escaped by default when you read a file. The reason why it works when you copy-paste it to a Python string is that the interpreter escapes the string.

```
with open('help/myhelp.help', encoding='unicode_escape') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals and https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html for detailed information on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os module so your code will be

```
import os
os.system('color a')
with open("help/myhelp.help", "r") as f:
for line in f:
      print(line)
```

and thus everything is done 
you can get the colors you need by changing `a` to some other letter or number.

[This link](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-command-prompt-color.html) helps to explain how to obtain the color codes.

Comment: so what do you want to do can you explain please.

Comment: you can use str() to convert it to string and get the escapes.,

Comment: can you tell me what will you do if the problem is solved or in simple words what is your project.